# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level for convert a video into frames

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am facing the following error:

> `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

Can anyone help me to correct this error?

```
path='/home/wajd/expl/mxnet-ssd/'

cap=cv2.VideoCapture('video7.avi')
while (True):

    ret, frame=  cap.read()

    if (ret==True):
        detector.detect_and_visualize(frame,cap, args.dir, args.extension,
                              class_names, args.thresh, args.show_timer)
        cv2.imshow(frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
```

'Break' has been indenten one time to many, which causes IndentationError. Try removing 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You have a double indent in your second if block. Removing it should solve the problem

```
path='/home/wajd/expl/mxnet-ssd/'

cap=cv2.VideoCapture('video7.avi')
while (True):

    ret, frame=  cap.read()

    if (ret==True):
        detector.detect_and_visualize(frame,cap, args.dir, args.extension,
                              class_names, args.thresh, args.show_timer)
        cv2.imshow(frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```